# Compare string "numerically first"

Tags: php, string, sorting, compare

I want to compare two string "numerically". I mean like `2C` is less than `11A`. I tried this and it's not working:

```
if("2A" < "11A"){
    echo "First corect";
}

if(strcmp("2A", "11A") < 0){
    echo "Last corect";
}

echo "Tests completed";
```

Comment: You have to separate the string tokens first by using regular expressions. Then you can sort the tokens first and recombine the result afterwards.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "numerically"?

Comment: are 2A and 11A hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: Are you sorting an array of those items or just two items?

Comment: @loler I think it means that first you compare them as if they were numbers (so 2<11) but if numbers are the same compare as strings. To the author: use type casting like in Anyone's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Why do we need string comparison function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255131/php-why-do-we-need-string-comparison-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) (or its case-insensitive sibling, [`strnatcasecmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php)).

This will compare the numeric parts of your input as numbers (placing "2whatever" before "11whatever") and the textual parts as text (placing "2a" before "2b").

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```php
if((int) '2A' < (int) '11A'){
    echo "First correct";
}
```

You can also take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(intval(0x2A) < intval(0x11A)){
    echo "First corect";
}
else
{
    echo "Tests incompleted";
}
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that:

1. Tokenizes each String into a List `<Object>` where each object can be a **String** or **Integer** with the Integers being created from a contiguous string of digits between non-digits, the Strings being contiguous non-digits between any 2 digits.
2. In a loop compare the two Lists element by element. If the type of the objects doesn't match (i.e. comparing an Integer to a String) make the less/greater decision on which you want to sort as smaller, letters or digits.  If they match just do a *less than*, *equals*, *greater than* comparison.
3. If the two `Nth elements` in the list are equal, go on to compare the `N+1th elements`, otherwise `return t/f` based on the integer to integer or string to string comparison.